# assignment shifts work with forecast curve

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, forecasting

I need to assign work shifts which follow a forecast curve.

example.

this is a forecast curve:

```
08:00        08:15 08:30 08:45 09:00 09:15 09:30 09:45 10:00 .....17:00
6(persons)   6     6     7     7     8     12    16    14         10
```

and I have shift preconfigured. example:

08:00 12:00,08:15 12:15,08:30 12:30,08:45 12:45,09:00 13:00.... 16:00 20:00, 16:15 20:15...

each person has their shift. example:

```
Carl  08:00 12:00
Rich  08:30 12:30
Jason 09:45 13:45
Louis 10:00 14:00
```

but are assigned at random. 
So, I'd like the curve, says that there are 6 people, must be obligatorily 6 people, at 08:00, then 6 people will turn that starts from 08:00.

then the situation would become this (suppose six people start at 08:00 to 12:00):

```
 08:00        08:15 08:30 08:45 09:00 09:15 09:30 09:45 10:00 .....12:00 13:00
 6(persons)   6     6     7     7     8     12    16    14         10    10
 6            6     6     6     6     6     6     6     6          6     0
```

Now comes the request.

I would like a script in php that would assign the random shifts, following the curve and changing the situation in this way.

```
 08:00        08:15 08:30 08:45 09:00 09:15 09:30 09:45 10:00 .....12:00  13:00
 6(persons)   6     6     7     7     8     12    16    14         10     10
 6            6     6     7     7     8     12    16    16         16     10
```

is not necessary that they are equal to the forecast. is impossible because the shifts are a minimum of 4 hours. It means that for four hours I will have 6 people (example)
then assigning shifts to the people:

```
Name  08:00 12:00(6 people start)
Name  08:45 12:45(1 person start)
Name  09:15 13:15(1 person start)
Name  09:30 13:30(4 people start)
```

this is my script to assign shifts random:

```
function sumatra($inizio,$plus){
        $accrued_time = strtotime($inizio);
     $current_session = strtotime($plus) - strtotime("00:00:00");
     return date("H:i", ($accrued_time + $current_session));
        }

$link=connect_db();


$sel="SELECT op.id, op.nome, op.cognome, op.ore_giornaliere_time, (
SELECT tp.inizio
FROM turni_preconf AS tp
WHERE tp.tot_ore = op.ore_giornaliere
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 1
) AS randomin
FROM operatori AS op";

$res_sel=mysql_query($sel,$link);


while($er=mysql_fetch_array($res_sel)){

    echo $er['nome'].' '.$er['cognome'].': '.remove_sec($er['randomin']).'/'.sumatra($er['randomin'],$er['ore_giornaliere_time']).'<br>';


    }
```

and this is my sql schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/043c0

Comment: Does your script not work? What is the expected output? What is the actual output? Is there a question hiding in there somewhere?

Comment: no my script output a random assignment but without following the curve